# Ruby - using class instance to access same named methods from different modules

Tags: ruby, module

I have 2 Modules M1 and M2 each containing same method name as met1

I have a class MyClass which includes these modules.
I create an instance test of MyClass, now I want to call met1 from each module.
Is it possible to do so?

here is the code:

```
module M1
def met1
    p "from M1 met1.."
end
end
module M2
def met1
    p "from M2 met1 ..."
end
end

class MyClass

include M1, M2
def met2
    p "met2 from my class"
end
end

test = MyClass.new
test.met1 # From module 1
test.met2 # from my class
test.met1 # from module 2 (how to ?)
```

Please let me know how to do this.

My output is

```
"from M1 met1.."
"met2 from my class"
"from M1 met1.."
```

This might be a very simple query but please answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now I want to call met1 from each module. Is it possible to do so?

Yes,possible. Use [***`Module#instance_method`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-instance_method) to create first `UnboundMethod`. Then do call [***`UnboundMethod#bind`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) to bind `test` object. Now you have [***`Method`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html) object with you. So call now [***`Method#call`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-call) to get your expected output.

```
module M1
  def met1
    p "from M1 met1.."
  end
end
module M2
  def met1
    p "from M2 met1 ..."
  end
end

class MyClass

  include M1, M2
  def met2
    p "met2 from my class"
  end
end

test = MyClass.new

test.class.included_modules.each do |m|
  m.instance_method(:met1).bind(test).call unless m == Kernel
end
# >> "from M1 met1.."
# >> "from M2 met1 ..."
```

Comment: +1. Is it just me, or is SO somewhat dead these days?

Comment: By the way, could you please explain me what does `m == Kernel` exactly means?

Comment: @rahoolm `Object` is a default superclass of `MyClass`. `Object` includes `Kernel`. So `Kernel` is included in `MyClass` too. But `meth` is not defined in that `Kernel` module.Thus to avoid `Kernel`, I used that if condition. Just do `test.class.included_modules`,you will get to see that.